# Hide <li> asp.net items depending on user privileges

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, hide

I have to hide column 4 when specific users log in to a website. This is my current code for asp and c#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((LoggedIn)Page.Master).CurrentPage = LoggedIn.LoggedInMenuPages.1;

            if (CurrentCustomer.AdminRole==false)
            {
               ******NEED TO HIDE ITEM 4
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `runat="server"` to the elements and also specific `ID`, after that go in `Page_Load` write the `ControlID.Visible=false`

**ASPX**

```
<li id="AdminElement" runat="server">
 //other tags
</li>
```

**Page_Load**

```
 AdminElement.Visible = CurrentCustomer.AdminRole;
 //remove the class attribute from the aspx
 AdminElement.Attributes["class"] = GetCurrentPageStyle("4");
```

Comment: I've tried doing that just before I posted this question but Visual Studio returns the following error: 
An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: @m_wilson
So set the class attribute of the li element in the Page_Load too. Remove it from aspx and in Page_Load something like this AdminElement.Attributes["class"] = GetCurrentPageStyle("4");

Comment: Thank you! I was actually placing the AdminElement.Attributes["class"] = GetCurrentPageStyle("4"); and AdminElement.Visible = false; into the wrong Page_load...how silly.

Comment: No worries, silly mistake happen to everybody, good luck with your project.